# Track external site with socket.io?

Tags: json, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Is there any way to track an external site with socket.io? So whenever the website changes then it would automatically send an event to my server?

For example:

```
socket.on("newconnectionfromxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", function (websiteChange)  {  //websiteChange would be the contents of the updated website.
});
```

Sorry if this questions is obvious because I couldn't find anything online.

EDIT: The site that I want to be tracking is a JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

socket.io works between two cooperating sites.  So, it would only help you here if the site you want to monitor specifically supports an incoming socket.io connection AND it supports sending a notification message over that connection whenever the specific file you are interested in changes.

If the site you want to monitor does not have such specific monitoring features, then the best you could do is to regularly download the file of interest and see for yourself if it has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Since all websites are not really fully event-driven/reactive at this time, you'll have to poll your website target periodically and look at that JSON file for differences.   There are many "filewatcher" programs (C#, Java, etc) out there that hook into the native OS filesystem event mechanisms; you could alter one of these programs to trigger an WS or HTTP event to your server.  There is a NodeJS wrapper that might be helpful for you: https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar

Bummer the Unix "watch" utility didn't have an option to trigger events when a diff was detected instead of visually highlighting the change.  It would be really cool if it has a "-difftrigger 'some-command'" option...